# Stopping a thread in an Android Service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have a Thread running in a Service... its run method looks something like this:

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       while(!finished){
          foo();
       }
       cleanUp();
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm starting the thread in the `onStartCommand` method of the service and I want to shut it down when the service stops. Now to stop the thread I'm setting the `finished` variable to `true` (in the service's `onDestroy` method).

```
    public void onDestroy() {
       ...
       finished = true;
       ...
    }
```

(turns out that it works just fine when I'm debugging the program -> `cleanUp` will be called as expected)

Without debugging it, `cleanUp` won't be called. Can anyone explain this to me? Where's my error? Thanks

Comment: Unsychronized multithreaded access to the finished variable is probably a big part of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a Thread synchronization issue since Debugger will serialize things for you and it works.

I would suggest using signaling to solve your problem.

One way is after setting isFinished=TRUE; do a wait(int timeout) and have the run loop (consumer class) to do notify();. This way even Consumer class is in bad state, you still get out after your timeout.

Comment: darn, I found the error. In  method `foo` I was actually accessing a blocking queue and the thread was waiting at queue.take() since the queue was empty. thus it never evaluated the while condition. I fixed it with interrupting the thread in `onDestroy`. thanks for your hint ;)